# How to downgrade Windows 7 to XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, downgrade

I have a small laptop with Windows 7 64-bit installed (no CD ROM drive). I have the installation files of Windows XP on a USB flash drive but it's not bootable. I want to remove Windows 7 completely and install XP.

When I simply run the setup file in USB, the "Install Windows XP" choice is not selectable and there's no explaination. I found some programs which can prepare a XP bootable disk on USB, but those programs won't run on 64-bit system either. Do I have any way ?

Comment: Please can you mention the exact configuration of your laptop and the brand, so I can help you quickly with a solution.

Comment: " I found some programs which can prepare a XP bootable disk on USB, but those programs won't run on 64-bit system either." - Which programs were these? [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/overview/en/), [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) and many more work fine on Win7 x64 and support transferring XP ISOs to USB.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Linux/Ubuntu tools. You might start with [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). It might be necessary that you download and provide a 32bit Ubuntu ISO to create the stick, but it should be bootable. You could then try to exchange the ubuntu files with your XP files. Once the stick has a proper boot sector, it should be fine. It should format as FAT32.

A second, maybe even better, option might be given at [How to boot from a USB device?](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/6609-how-to-boot-from-a-usb-device).

Good luck.